# Replacement for “overcome”

Tags: sentence-construction

Could you please suggest some words to replace "overcome"?

> On the other hand, the development achieved in computer hardware and
>   software has made computational fluid dynamics (CFD) methods become an
>   alternative tool to **overcome** the aforementioned problem.

Comment: What English language dictionary did you consult to learn the meaning of the verb _overcome?_ If that meaning confuses you, you should add this to your question by using the [edit] link.

Comment: can you suggest me a good dictionary?

Comment: Yes! The site at [**OneLook.com**](http://Onelook.com) provides links to many dictionaries on one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few edits may be needed here in the first instance:

> On the other hand, developments achieved in computer hardware and software enabled computational fluid dynamics (CFD) methods to emerge as an alternative tool to *overcome* the aforementioned problem.

In this case, we assume that there was a challenge or problem identified in the prior sentence. The word *overcome* is used to mean either ***to solve*** or ***to get beyond***.